# Automatic null assert in scala

Tags: scala, macros

I would like to use `!` symbol to automatically generate non-null assert in Scala. I mean that in a situation like this:

```
class Person(val name:String) {
  assert(name != null)  
}
```

all other integrity checks can be solved by having custom argument type, but null check is always required to be written again and again. Could I have just something like this?

```
class Person(val name:String!) // note the bang (!)
```

and have that assert be generated? Are there any simple macros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get something sort of similar via an implicit class.

```
implicit class StringCheck(str :String) {
  def ! :String = {assert(str != null); str}
}
```

With this the null test syntax is reduced...

```
import scala.language.postfixOps
class Person(val name:String) {name!}
```

...or perhaps inserted in other code.

```
class Person(val name:String) {
  if (name.!.length > 10) ...
  else ...  
}
```

---

A more generalized version as suggested by @simpadjo.

```
implicit class NotNullSupport[T](val obj :T) extends AnyVal {
  def ! : T = {assert(obj != null); obj}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could it work with any type by chance? Not just `String`?

Comment: I think you'll need to have an implicit class for each specific type. Implicit conversion doesn't work well with generic types.

Comment: Sure you can: 

implicit class NotNullSupport[T](val obj :T) extends AnyVal {
    def ! : T = {assert(obj != null); obj}
  }

Comment: @jwvh Why do you think so? Look at https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.5/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L306-L327.

Comment: @simpadjo & @AlexeyRomanov; You are both right, of course. My initial tests were discouraging but hastily put together (I had little time at the time). That and the fact that the IntelliJ IDE doesn't like value classes, so I jumped to the wrong conclusion. My bad.

Comment: @jwvh  I tried to use the latest version in `class Name(val first:String, val last:String) { first!; last! }`. The error is `value class may not be a member of another class`. The same time, `implicit class NotNullAssert(that: Any) { def ! = assert(that != null) }` works fine.

Comment: @DmitryNogin; A "value class", i.e. `extends AnyVal`, cannot be inside another class and, as such, also doesn't work in the IntelliJ scratch-pad/worksheet. If you want the `NotNull` class inside another class then take out the `extends AnyVal` and see if that works.